# Counting cats with regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

So I want to match a string with the word "cat" in it a bunch of times, such as:

```
"cat cat cat cat cat"
```

or

```
"cat   cat cat  cat"
```

If there's anything else besides "cat" or whitespace, I don't want to match.  So I can do:

```
^(cat\s*)+$
```

However, I want to find out how many cats appear in the string.  One way to do this would be to count the number of groups, however the above regular expression will only give me a single group with the first cat, not a capture per cat.  Is there a way to do this using regular expressions?

Comment: `/(cat\s*)/g` gives you an array of `cat`s in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, but that will also match "cat cat cat dog" which I don't want.

Comment: If it makes a diff, this code is written in Ruby..  I think I have an answer but want to see if there's a better way.

Comment: You can't use that regexp. It will give a wrong result. See my answer.

Comment: I think your question may possibly be misleading. You have the sentence "... anything besides 'cat' or whitespace, I don't want to match". If you were interested in just counting the number of 'cat', then you shouldn't need to mention about **whitespace**. Therefore, I interpreted what you mean by "I don't want to match" that you want to return nil in such case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do two different things - validate a string and count word occurrences. Usually you cannot do these two things in one step.

```
var str   = "cat cat cat cat cat";
var count = 0;

if ( /^(cat\s*)+$/.test(str) ) {
  count = str.match(/cat/g).length;
}
```

In .NET regex you have [Group.Captures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures.aspx) which lists all the occurrences where a group matched, not just the last one, like in other regex engines. Here you could do both validating and counting in one step.

Comment: This is the conclusion I came to as well.  I ended up just using the RegEx as is, then rather than looking at a group array, I can do: "cat cat cat".scan('cat').count

Comment: @Mike: Yes, that's basically the same thing my JS example does.

Comment: @sawa: Umm... `"catcatcatcatcat".match(/cat/g).length` == 5. Seems correct to me.

Comment: You want to consider 'catcat' as two instances of the word 'cat'? Then you are correct, but I didn't assume that.

Comment: @sawa: Well, I would not know *what else* I could consider `"catcat"` as. Just like I would consider `"AA"` as two instances of `"A"`. ;-)

Comment: When you are counting the **character** 'A', it may make sense to count 'AA' as two 'A', but when you are looking at **words**, I think it is natural to say that 'catcat' is not two 'cat's. I think 'catcat' fits into the category of "anything besides of 'cat' and whitespace" in Mike's question.

Comment: @sawa: Fair enough. I guess only the OP can tell. Firstly: it looks as though he knows enough about regex to be able to figure out an expression that works for him. Secondly: I suppose `"cat"` is just a placeholder for what he's *really* looking for. It might not be words in the lingual sense after all. And thirdly: Whether my answer counts correctly is besides the point of the question. :)

Comment: @Tomalak - Your answer is perfect.  You're right, I'm not actually looking for cats, that was just an example.  However, your technique of using a regex to "verify" and then another function (in my case, the scan function in Ruby) to count is a fantastic solution.  This is why I marked your response as the chosen answer.  There probably is some nifty pure regex way of doing it, but really who cares and it's sure to be platform dependent.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see anyone mentioning what I consider the obvious answer, using String#scan:

```
str = "cat cat cat    catcat"
str.scan('cat').size #=> 5
```

If you just *have* to use a regex:

```
str.scan(/cat/).size #=> 5
```

If you want to only catch unique, not run-together, occurrences:

```
str.scan(/\bcat\b/).size #=> 3
```

---

EDIT:

@sawa points out that there is (considerable) room for misinterpretation of the OP's question. This covers cases where the OP didn't want a search to occur if something besides `cat` and `" "` was in the string.

```
str.scan('cat').size if str.gsub(/(?:cat| )+/, '').empty? #=> 5
```

The other variations in my previous section can still be applied.

And, since "whitespace" could mean more than a simple space, `"\s"` should also work fine.

Comment: I think your answer is straightforward under one interpretation of Mike's question. I think the question may possibly be misleading or unclear. Mike says "I don't want to match" when there is "anything else besides 'cat' or whitespace". If he simply wants to count "cat", then he didn't need to mention "whitespace". Therefore, I took it that he doesn't want to return the count for the whole string when the string includes such characters.

Answer (score 3):

Note that Mike's original regexp as well as Tomalak, Marten, tagman's answer all give the wrong count when the string includes instances of 'cat' that are consecutive (unless you want to consider 'catcat' as two instances of the word 'cat'). The following does not meet this problem.

```
def count_if_match
  delimiters = strip.split('cat')
  delimiters.length+1 if delimiters.all?{|s| s =~ / +/}
end

' cat   cat cat  cat'.count_if_match # => 4
' catcat cat cat'.count_if_match # => nil
```

Comment: Agreed - In my particular situation, this doesn't matter (I'm not /actually/ looking for cats) but it's good to point this out.

Answer (score 0):

Consider translating whitespaces to newlines, then count the lines matching the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the last cat you're capturing. That happens because of the [greediness of + and the way capture groups work](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html). I don't think it's possible to get more than one capture out of a group. The best thing you can do is probably:

```
str = "cat   cat cat  cat"

matchdata = str.match(/^((?:cat\s*)+)$/)
=> #<MatchData "cat   cat cat  cat" 1:"cat   cat cat  cat"> 

matchdata[0].split(/\s+/).size
=> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

A Ruby way without regex would be:

```
string = "cat   cat cat  cat"
def match_cat(string)
  cat_array = string.split
  count = cat_array.size
  cat_array.uniq == ["cat"] ? count : false
end
match_cat(string)
=> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"cat   cat cat  cat".split.count{|w|
    break false unless w == 'cat'

    true
}
```